# random subspace ensemble classifier python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, keras

i am in python i search for implementation for random subspace ensemble classifier , and i found the following code in github

```
https://github.com/mwygoda/randomSubspaceImplementation/blob/master/solution.py
```

author depend in this two lib

```
from utils import prepare_data_from_file
 from utils import plot_results
```

i  try to install utils using pip3, it installed and worked when i run `import utils as ut` put still get error cannot import name 'plot_results' or'prepare_data_from_file' 
any one help me how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

That file is not in the repo. You will have to implement it yourself.
from the code it looks like it returns a feature vector and target labels.

e.g

```
def prepare_data_from_file(file):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    return df['A'], df['B']
```

But this is mere speculation. Now get off stackoverflow and go do your assisgnment.

Comment: my question is how to specify many X , each X run on different classifier

Comment: Put the clf.fit() method in a loop. Pass the same x. And note metrics.

Comment: i will clarify to you , i have six feature subset , for each of them i try multiple classifiers , reach to the most suitable algorithm for each one ... my question now how to combine them using ensemble classifier like bagging, adaboost, voting ,etc